# Overwriting a cookie is failing in IE11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, tomcat, cookies

Here's the scenario:

1. Login as User A -  Sets a JSESSIONID cookie
2. Logout
3. Login as User B - Attempts to overwrite the JSESSIONID in IE with the new one
4. Subsequent calls to the server no longer have a JSESSIONID cookie sent in the headers

Here is what the traffic looks like:
[image: traffic summary]

Here is what it looks like when the 2nd login attempts to "overwrite" the JSESSIONID cookie
[image: 2nd Login]

You can see here that the "old" JSESSIONID ("DSE6...") was Sent to the server, but that the "new" JSESSIONID ("CD26...") was Received.

A few other details:

- Tomcat 7.x is on the server-side
- Using httpOnly, secure cookies
- This is ONLY an issue in IE; everything works fine in Chrome and FF

**So the question is: why is IE forgetting the JSESSIONID when the server attempts to overwrite it?**

Comment: Couple of ideas. Is login is storing the credentials in the incoming session, then starting a new session (that does not contain the credentials)? Do the "domain" and "path" match between the two "Set-cookie" headers?

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller The domain and path do match between the 2 Set-Cookie headers. Not sure about the credentials question.

Comment: Try having the logout expire the session cookie by getting the cookie from the request, setting the value to null and the maxAge to 0 and adding it to the response.

Comment: @caleb, Did you ever get any insight into this issue? I'm having what looks like a possibly related issue with IE11 sometimes not sending the JSESSIONID and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: @Pyro979 Afraid not.